How to say/pronounce "[City Name] proper" in Japanese
According to google translate, for example if you wanted to say "Chicago proper" (as in within city limits and not the nearby suburbs), you would say "シカゴ市内". Is this correct?
Also, given that the pronunciation is "しない", that seems like it could create some confusion. Is there a particular way to pronounce 市内 vs しない as in the negative of "to do" to make sure you never get them confused?

I don't worry about pitch, so I never think about it.  But I'd say it's probably [市内]{HL} vs. [しない]{LLH}.

Unless シカゴする is a verb, I don't see how anyone would think シカゴしない is the negative of to do, especially when 市内 is almost always followed by に or で

@dvx2718 - Yeah, it's hard to imagine even 甲府市内 and 交付しない causing any confusion.

Note that it contains 市, so you need to adjust to the appropriate title or status of the region you mention. For example, as a special case, "Tokyo proper" would be 都内.
